# What is the difference between an active and inactive T helper cell?

Tags: human-biology, immunology, pathology, immune-system, immunity

1- Are all inactive T helper cells "T memory cells" ?
2- Is there anything such as active T memory cells ? 
3- I have noticed that there is also a third type of T helper cells but i dont know what it is called. They are used in the beginning of the humoral response process (they bind to initial APC cells and then divide producing active t helper cells and inactive t memory cells). How are these different from the active and inactive T helper cells ?